# i need pass a variable JavaScript to path method in symfony

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, path

I have the next route in Symfony:

```
 path: /BuscarCriterio/{nombre}
```

How Can i pass the Variable {nombre} with JavaScript?

```
var nombre=$('#form_nombre').val();

            var Ruta= "{{ path('BuscarporCriterio',{'nombre':I need my JS Variable Here }) }}";
```

it is necessary to know i can't use window.location because i need this route for make a call to Ajax.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOSJsRoutingBundle can be used to generate paths in javascript files https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Install the bundle and try this inside a js file

```
var nombre = $('#form_nombre').val();
var Ruta = Routing.generate('BuscarporCriterio', { nombre: nombre });
```

Comment: Amazing! i did it. Thank you Very much.

Comment: This can't work ! var nombre is js, when used in path function it's twig.

Comment: @COil It was tested and it works if written inside a twig template like I said.

Comment: @DiegoBastidas You are welcome. Remember that you should write your js code in .js files, and to generate your paths use the FOSJsRoutingBundle.

Comment: Just tested your snippet; symfony exception: "Variable "nombre" does not exist." `{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

    var nombre = $('#form_nombre').val();
    var Ruta = "{{ path('home_page', { nombre: nombre }) }}";

{% endblock %}
`

Comment: @COil You should obviously put your js code inside a <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag

Comment: Same error. What is obvious it that you didn't test your snippet. Try by yourself.

Comment: @COil I tested the path generation inside a script tag, not the var thing, you are right. Ive updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.